# Typescript generic type concatenation when using a recursive concat method inside a monad

Tags: typescript, generics, concatenation, monads

I have implemented a Result monad which almost works :)

```
class Result<T> {
  private readonly value: T;
  private readonly error: Error;

  constructor(value?: T, error?: Error) {
    if (value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    if (error) {
      this.error = error;
    }
  }

  static ok<T>(ok: T): Result<T> {
    return new Result<T>(ok);
  }

  static error<T>(err: Error): Result<T> {
    return new Result<T>(undefined, err);
  }

  isOk(): boolean {
    return this.value !== undefined;
  }

  isError(): boolean {
    return this.error !== undefined;
  }

  chain<U>(f: (t: T) => Result<U>): Result<U> {
    return this.isOk() ?
      f(this.value) :
      Result.error<U>(this.error);
  }

  map<U>(f: (t: T) => U): Result<U> {
    return this.isOk() ?
      Result.ok<U>(f(this.value)) :
      Result.error<U>(this.error);
  }

  concat<U>(aResult: Result<U>): Result<(T | U)[]> {
    return this.isOk() ?
      Result.ok<(T | U)[]>(Array().concat(this.value, aResult.getValue())) :
      Result.error(this.error);
  }

  getError(): Error {
    return this.error;
  }

  getValue(): T {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

This is how you use it:

```
 const r1 = Result.ok(76)
      .concat(Result.ok('ddd'))
      .concat(Result.ok(true))
      .map((i: (number | string | boolean)[]) => i);
```

Here, I concatenate three results: a number, a string and a boolean.

After that, I want to map them and apply a transformation method.

The method **.map** should take a typed **(number | string | boolean)[]** as a parameter.

But, I get the following error message:[image]

I know what the problem is, but I do now know how to solve it.

The issue is with the **.concat** method:

```
concat<U>(aResult: Result<U>): Result<(T | U)[]> {
        return this.isOk() ?
          Result.ok<(T | U)[]>(Array().concat(this.value, aResult.getValue())) :
          Result.error(this.error);
      }
```

This method is called each time a concatenation happens, "recursively" if you wish.

So, in my case, this is the flow:

1. first concat - **U** is the string **'ddd'** and **T** is the **76** number. The method returns a **(number | string)[]**
2. second concat - **U** is already a **(number | string)[]** and it takes a boolean. Typescript, instead of returning **(number | string | boolean)[]**, returns **(boolean | (number | string)[])[]**

Can I make the concat method behave and accept the (string | number | boolean)[] signature?

Any ideas?

Comment: this isnt exactly an answer but I almost always implement concat as a separate function rather than an instance method. It has this type: 

<A,B,C=any,...>(ms: [M<A>, M<B>, M<C>?, ...]) => M<[A,B,C,...]>

you can then chain into the data type and return the result of concat-ing several things together instead of using the concat instance method. It tends to infer types very well and lets you use array destructuring when you want to map on the result of concat. 
The downside is you must hardcode up to n optional type arguments to be able to call concat on a list of n items.

Answer (score 0):

If  `T` is already an array you should return `(TElement | U)[]`. You can add an extra overload for when `this` has a `T` of an array type:

```
concat<TElement, U>(this: Result<TElement[]>,  aResult: Result<U>): Result<(TElement | U)[]>
concat<U>(aResult: Result<U>): Result<(T | U)[]>
concat<U>(aResult: Result<U>): Result<(T | U)[]> {
  return this.isOk() ?
    Result.ok<(T | U)[]>(Array().concat(this.value, aResult.getValue())) :
    Result.error(this.error);
}
```

Or you can use a conditional type, which at the call-site will work the same, but y ou will need a type assertion in the function, but you will have less overloads to take care of :

```
concat<U>(aResult: Result<U>): Result<( (T extends (infer TElement)[] ? TElement : T ) | U)[]> {
  return this.isOk() ?
    Result.ok<(T | U)[]>(Array().concat(this.value, aResult.getValue())) :
    Result.error(this.error) as any;
}
```